A recursion for the coefficients of the frequencies of $(2\cos(X))^n$
Inspired by my alternate answer to this question, I was investigating powers of cosine when turned into frequencies. The rule was: take $(2\cos(X))^n$, turn it into a sum of frequencies (that is, things of the form $\cos(kX)$ instead of $\cos(X)^k$), and (for clarity) replace $\cos(kX)$ with $y^k$. The results were:
$$\begin{array}{l}2y\\2y^2+2\\2y^3+6y\\2y^4+8y^2+6\\2y^5+10y^3+20y\\2y^6+12y^4+30y^2+20\\2y^7+14y^5+42y^3+70y\\2y^8+16y^6+56y^4+112y^2+70\\2y^9+18y^7+72y^5+168y^3+252y\\2y^{10}+20y^8+90y^6+240y^4+420y^2+252\\2y^{11}+22y^9+110y^7+330y^5+660y^3+924y\\2y^{12}+24y^{10}+132y^8+440y^6+990y^4+1584y^2+924\\\end{array}$$
I stared at this for a while, and was able to see a recursion that was nearly identical to the recursion for the binomial coefficients in Pascal's triangle. Let $c_{n,k}$ denote the coefficient of $y^k$ in row $n$. Then, with appropriate initial conditions,
$$
\begin{cases}
c_{n,k} = c_{n-1,k-1}+c_{n-1,k+1},&k\ne 1\\
c_{n,1} = 2c_{n-1,0} + c_{n-1,2}
\end{cases}
$$For instance, this says $72=c_{9,5}=c_{8,4}+c_{8,6}=56+16$ and $252=c_{9,1}=2c_{8,0}+c_{8,2}=2\cdot 70+112$.
What struck me is that, aside from the presence of $2$ in the $c_{n-1,0}$ term, this is very similar to the binomial recurrence: each term is found from the terms to the upper right and upper left, so to speak. However, though I am reasonably familiar with the trig functions and the Chebyshev polynomials, I have not seen this recurrence given so explicitly in any literature. I would be shocked if this was not known, so I am requesting a source giving this recursion.

On further thought, the $2$ isn't really exceptional: it's the same formula, but uses the parity of cosine to get $\cos(X)=\cos(-X)$. I think the recurrence then follows directly from angle-addition, so it's not a big surprise. I will leave this up, but I don't think a reference is super necessary.

Noting that $2\cos(\theta) = e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}$, it is the variance from Pascal's triangle that is more surprising.
